# GTK : wait for user input

Tags: c, visual-c++, gtk

I am using GTK in C and I would like to make a form in order to collect input from user. I use GTK_ENTRY in order to collect user's input.

Unfortunately I don't know how I can put the execution is "pause" in order to wait that user enters its input and resume it as soon as the input is ready.

Can you help me, please?

Thanks

Comment: try a `system("pause")` , I know most people hate it (I do to) but maybe it'll work for you

Comment: In two words: You don't. Instead you have your event loop, and when the form is dismissed by the user (either by an "Ok" button or by a "Cancel" button) you will get an event about it.

Comment: thanks for your input.
Can you share an example of code? I tried to use a loop, even with mutex, but my program simply "freezes". Thanks

Comment: eventloop does not yield a threaded approach, thus (in this case) no mutexes are required (also GMutex is not multilockable which is probably the reason for your deadlock, it is undefined bahviour what you seem to do). There are tons of open source projects using gtk+, there are tutorials for beginners... also show what you tried.

Comment: thanks. Since I cannot find for my specific example, can you share them, please?

Answer (score 0):

```
#include <gtk/gtk.h>

static void on_button_clicked(GtkButton *button,gpointer data);
static void on_entry_activate(GtkEntry *entry,gpointer data);

int main(int argc, char *argv[])
{
    GtkWidget *window;
    GtkWidget *entry;
    GtkWidget *button;
    GtkWidget *hbox;

    gtk_init(&argc,&argv);
    window=gtk_window_new(GTK_WINDOW_TOPLEVEL);
    gtk_window_set_title(GTK_WINDOW(window),"entry");
    gtk_window_set_position(GTK_WINDOW(window),GTK_WIN_POS_CENTER);
    gtk_container_set_border_width(GTK_CONTAINER(window),5);

    hbox=gtk_box_new(GTK_ORIENTATION_HORIZONTAL,5);
    gtk_container_add(GTK_CONTAINER(window),hbox);

    entry=gtk_entry_new();
    gtk_box_pack_start(GTK_BOX(hbox),entry,TRUE,TRUE,5);

    button=gtk_button_new_with_label("Ok");
    gtk_box_pack_start(GTK_BOX(hbox),button,FALSE,FALSE,0);

    g_signal_connect(G_OBJECT(window),"destroy",
                G_CALLBACK(gtk_main_quit),NULL);
    g_signal_connect(G_OBJECT(button),"clicked",
                G_CALLBACK(on_button_clicked),entry);
    g_signal_connect(G_OBJECT(entry),"activate",/* when you press ENTER */
                G_CALLBACK(on_entry_activate),NULL);

    gtk_widget_show_all(window);
    gtk_main();

    return 0;
}

static void on_button_clicked(GtkButton *button,gpointer data)
{
    GtkWidget *entry=(GtkWidget *)data;
    GtkWidget *dialog;
    gchar buff[1024];

    g_snprintf(buff,1024,"You input '%s' !",
                gtk_entry_get_text(GTK_ENTRY(entry)));

    dialog=gtk_message_dialog_new(NULL,GTK_DIALOG_MODAL,
                GTK_MESSAGE_INFO,GTK_BUTTONS_OK,"%s",buff);
    gtk_dialog_run(GTK_DIALOG(dialog));

    gtk_widget_destroy(dialog);
    gtk_entry_set_text(GTK_ENTRY(entry),"");
}

static void on_entry_activate(GtkEntry *entry,gpointer data)
{
    g_printf("%s\n",gtk_entry_get_text(GTK_ENTRY(entry)));
}
```

This example is very simple. Input is ready when user press ENTER in entry or click OK BUTTON
The code is very easy to read, i think. Good luck!

Comment: Thanks for your code!
I could make a similar solution, but what I am still missing is the part of code which is waiting for user input. I will try to be clearer. Let's image that by pressing a button I launch a function and during its execution required user input. How can I "pause" the execution, waiting for the user entry and retrieve it? Thanks

Comment: I not understand exactly.You mean when the user press a button, a input dialog should show to let user input data?

Comment: where will you get the user input? a existing GtkEntry or a new one? If a new GtkEntry, maybe GtkDialog can help